# Getting child content

Tags: pages

I am using the folowing to get child title and content. Each child has a gallery and a short code in the content editor in the content, but I only get the gallery and not shortcode. It isn't something to do with the short code but rather on the content as I tried to add some paragraph to the content after the gallery and it does not show up.

```
<?php $pages = get_pages('child_of='.$page->ID.'&sort_order=asc&number=3&sort_column=menu_order&parent='.$page->ID);
foreach($pages as $page) {
    $content = $page->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
?>

    <div class="span4">
       <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>
        <?php echo $content ?>
    </div>
```

I think `$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);` is basically stripping out part of the content

Any idea why the shortcode isn't showing?

Comment: hmm, ok, just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i resolved it:

```
   <?php
 /*
 Template Name: home
*/
 get_header(); ?>

<?php $counter = 1 ?>
 <div class="row-fluid"> 
     <?php
    $args = array(
'child_of' => 4,
'parent' => 0,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
 ); 
 $childrens = query_posts('showposts=3&post_parent=4&post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=DESC');

 foreach ( $childrens as $children ) :
query_posts('showposts=3&post_parent='.$children->ID.'&post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=DESC');
if ( have_posts ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
        <div class="span4">
            <h2>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
<? if ($counter % 3 == 0): ?>
<div id="content" class="row-fluid"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $counter++; ?>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
    endforeach;
?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you to use `WP_Query` to fetch pages from db:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_parent'    => $page->ID,
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();

    ?>
    <div class="span4">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content() ?>
    </div>
    <?php
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also be careful! You use `$page` variable at first line of your snippet as already defined, and then you re declare it again when you use it in the `foreach` loop at the 2nd line of your snippet.

Comment: Thanks but the content isn't showing up, only the titles. This is the full code I am using: http://pastebin.com/9UMAEaLX

Baically I have "Home" with 3 categories and each category has childs. I need to be able to show each category title and each child tilte and content.  Finally limit the childs to be 3 per category. I am styling each category in a row. By using that full code in pastebin, which uses yours, I am only displaying the category titles and nothing more.